# Which tools do you use to debug HTML/JS in your browser?

Tags: javascript, html, debugging, browser

I'd like to collect the best debugging aids for all browsers out there. So that would probably be [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/1843) for Firefox but what do you use for IE? Safari? Opera? Opera Mini? What else is out there? Are there tools that work well for IE 6? IE 5?

Comment: and now for a follow-up question as to why there are absolutely zero equivalent tools for debugging directly on android (i.e. none of the remote crap that won't work in the field when you don't have an internet connection or non-android device available.)

Comment: @Michael: Ask the question and post the link as a comment here :-)

Answer (score 13):

For Firefox (any version > 2.0), use [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/1843).

Comment: I'm posting this for completeness and so we can use voting to find a better tool (if there should be one :)

Comment: Firebug beats everything. The only thing it can't do is find IE rendering errors, at which point you're back to the horror of web development in IE.

Comment: disagree.  I found Firebug to be so horrible I abandoned Firefox for Chrome, which has an integrated debugger that is actually not buggy.

Comment: @Michael: That sounds like you found one feature of Firebug lacking; I have had problems with JS debugging on all platforms (Chrome ignored breakpoints when the window was closed in the JS code, Firebug wouldn't let me set breakpoints, ...)

Answer (score 13):

[Here is a roundup](http://www.favbrowser.com/internet-explorer-developer-tools-vs-firefox-firebug-vs-safari-web-inspector-vs-opera-dragonfly/)

- Firefox has [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/1843) and Webdeveloper Toolbar,
- Safari and Chrome has the Inspector,
- Opera has Dragonfly,
- Internet Explorer has the Developer Toolbar

Firebug still has the most advanced features, but the others are catching up.

Comment: +1 for chrome Dev Tools, in my opinion far better than Firebug;

Answer (score 5):

For IE, either the Developer Tools included in IE 8 or the [Developer Toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=E59C3964-672D-4511-BB3E-2D5E1DB91038&displaylang=en).

Comment: IE 6 and 7. The Dev Tools in IE 8 are superior anyway so nothing's missing there.

Answer (score 4):

For Chrome, [Chrome Dev Tools](http://www.chromium.org/devtools).

Answer (score 4):

1. [IETester](http://my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage) for IE-versions.
2. [Adobe BrowserLab](https://browserlab.adobe.com/index.html) or [SuperPreview extension for IE](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=8e6ac106-525d-45d0-84db-dccff3fae677&displaylang=en) for testing designs in multiple browsers.
3. [Developer Toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=e59c3964-672d-4511-bb3e-2d5e1db91038&displaylang=en) for IE.
4. And ofc Firebug for FIrefox.

Answer (score 4):

In Internet Explorer or other Browsers than FireFox:

[FireBug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/lite.html)

Answer (score 3):

For debugging, nothing can beat [firefox:firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843)
and for IE, if [once in a blue moon](http://www.google.com/search?q=once+in+a+blue+moon) i use IE, i use, [Internet Explorer Developer Toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=e59c3964-672d-4511-bb3e-2d5e1db91038&displaylang=en)

Answer (score 3):

The [Speed Tracer](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/ognampngfcbddbfemdapefohjiobgbdl) extension for Google Chrome looks extremely useful.

Answer (score 2):

[dynaTrace Ajax](http://ajax.dynatrace.com/pages/) for [Deep Tracing of Internet Explorer](http://ejohn.org/blog/deep-tracing-of-internet-explorer/)

Answer (score 2):

- Fiddler http(s) debugging: http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/
- Web Developer toolbar for FireFox: https://addons.mozilla.org/nl/firefox/addon/60/
- IE8 Developer Tools: [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ie/introducing-the-ie8-developer-tools-jscript-profiler)
- qooxdoo Inspector (IE, Firefox, Opera, Safari and Chrome): http://qooxdoo.org/application/inspector
- Blackbird - You might never use alert() again: http://www.gscottolson.com/blackbirdjs/

Answer (score 1):

Firebug / Firebug lite of course :) Google Chrome's JS console is also very nice

Answer (score 1):

Cross-browser: [x-ray](http://www.westciv.com/xray/)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use a `DIV` with the `id="debug"` and then add text to it for debugging. That allows you to overlay the HTML with the debug output and it doesn't block the flow of the app. Use a `z-index` to make sure it stays on top and give it transparency so you can see through it. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183633/can-you-overlay-a-transparent-div-on-an-image/1183647#1183647) for the CSS.

Or open a new window and append your debug messages there.

You can use this with nested `DIV`s to implement full-fledged logging. Have a look at [this article on A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/jslogging) and at [log4js](http://log4js.sourceforge.net/) to get some ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Firebug is not the most lightweight tool, so I sometimes use other add-ons for Firefox:

- If you're playing with XPath, [XPath Checker](https://addons.mozilla.org/pl/firefox/addon/xpath-checker/) is handy and lightweight. I tweaked it on my own however to display the HTML source of results as text rather than as HTML nodes.
- [Tamper Data](https://web.archive.org/web/20180826084835/https://addons.mozilla.org/pl/firefox/addon/tamper-data/) or [HttpFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/pl/firefox/addon/httpfox/) are useful to see the request from webpages (well, AdBlock Plus also can be;), see the cookies being set by the web server etc.

Answer (score 0):

For Firefox 3.5, use Firebug. For IE8, use Developer Tools

Answer (score 0):

Using Firefox, in addition to Firebug (as many have previously mentioned) I find Mozilla's **[Venkman JavaScript debugger](https://web.archive.org/web/20110514003119/http://www.mozilla.org/projects/venkman/)** rather handy from time to time too.

Answer (score 0):

A series of strategically placed window.alert function calls is handy in a pinch. If I can, I try to use [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite).

Comment: Handy but also blocks the flow of the app.