# Firebug alternative for the IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox, firebug

Is there a good alternative to Firebug that I could use with IE 7 and 8?

I'm interested in modifying CSS/HTML on the go, as well as debugging some of the java script and viewing the positions of certain elements on the page.

THank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which tools do you use to debug HTML/JS in your browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887216/which-tools-do-you-use-to-debug-html-js-in-your-browser)

Comment: Aaron thank you for the link. X-Ray is what I'm after

Answer (score 10, accepted):

IE8 (also IE7) comes with Developer Tools. You can use it for debugging and a lot of things.

Comment: I have been using developer tools for debugging the javascript, but mainly i'm interesting in coordinates and styling of certain divs on the page. I'd like to select an element (e.g. div or image) and view it's coordinates and the CSS associated with that element.

Comment: This can be done in DT. Once DT is open click Ctrl+B then you should be able to select an element. Then you can use the Style and Layout tabs to see CSS and co-ordinates

Comment: Yes, you can inspect the DOM, CSS, layout, attributes etc.

Answer (score 7):

There is something called firebuglite which is a subset of firebug.  It works in IE6+ browsers.  Checkout the following link for more info:

http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite

Answer (score 4):

Press F12 (or Tools/Developer Tools on menu) in IE to open the Developer Tools - this has some of the functionality of Firebug, including editing CSS on the go and debugging Javascript

Answer (score 1):

The best JavaScript debugger for IE is probably Visual Studio. Developer Tools would probably cover your needs, but if you feel you need more power then check out Visual Studio. There's a [free version](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Web/), haven't tried the 2010 version though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you get something like firebug for the IE but you can debug your page by `checking` the `Disable Script Debugger` from the IE Tools options.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [firebug](http://www.firebugger.com) for ie if you use internet explorer

Comment: He just said he wants an alternative to Firebug.

Comment: CAREFUL! This link is now a spammy site offering adult services. Do not go there!

Answer (score 0):

Developer Tools is mentioned by many here, and is probably what you're looking for. But if you also need to analyze performance, something similar to yslow, then [Dynatrace](http://ajax.dynatrace.com) is worth a look.

Answer (score 0):

In reality, there's no good alternative of firebug, neither in ie nor in chrome. All forums on following topic are just there to waste the time. The best option in chrome and ie is to press F12.