# equivalent to firebug in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, debugging

what is the equivalent debug tool to FireFox firebug in Internet Explorer ?

thanks

EDIT:
What is this tool ?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which tools do you use to debug HTML/JS in your browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887216/which-tools-do-you-use-to-debug-html-js-in-your-browser)

Comment: do you have a specific version of IE?  because IE8 includes built in Developer Tools similar to Firebug

Comment: @leppie Firebug and developer tools both let you debug javascript...

Comment: @Zachary: Ah, never knew that, thanks  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is
http://www.httpwatch.com/

which seems an excellent tool and the only match for firebug

thanks for all efforts

Answer (score 5):

Click on "Tools" and then "Developer tools".

Or hit F12.

Answer (score 2):

IE Developer toolbar http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=e59c3964-672d-4511-bb3e-2d5e1db91038&displaylang=en

Answer (score 1):

There's firebug lite:

http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite

Answer (score 1):

You can use the debugger in Visual Studio to debug Javascript in IE.

Answer (score 0):

In IE 8, they have this "Developer Tools" found under "Tools" located upper right.

It's not as great as firebug though but quite similar in nature.