# Tool Roundup for Debugging JavaScript

Tags: javascript, debugging, cross-browser

What techniques (other than `alert(message);`) do you use to debug JavaScript/jQuery? Give particular attention to browser specific techniques.

### Tools

- `console.log(message)` - alternative to `alert(message);` ([Nirmal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023971/debugging-javascript/4024117#4024117))

  - browser-safe call ([soslo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023971/debugging-javascript/4024198#4024198))
- [jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/) - demonstrations ([Craver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023971/debugging-javascript/4023993#4023993))
- [BlackBird](http://ttp://www.gscottolson.com/blackbirdjs/) - writing messages to the screen ([Oli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023971/debugging-javascript/4024057#4024057))

### FireFox

- [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) ([Lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite))
- [Venkman's JS Debugger Add-in](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/venkman/) ([Zeus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887216/which-tools-do-you-use-to-debug-html-js-in-your-browser/3263815#3263815))

### Chrome

- Built-in [development tools](http://www.chromium.org/devtools) ([tutorial](http://www.chromium.org/devtools/google-chrome-developer-tools-tutorial))
- [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite) (extension)

### Safari

- Built-in tools ([overview](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/1Introduction/Introduction.html) - [jsummers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023971/debugging-javascript/4024239#4024239)) ([more information](http://hicksdesign.co.uk/journal/web-development-with-safari))

### Opera

- [Dragonfly](http://www.opera.com/dragonfly/)

### Internet Explorer (*I had to put it last*)

- [Developer Toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=95e06cbe-4940-4218-b75d-b8856fced535)
- [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite)
- [Adobe BrowserLab](https://browserlab.adobe.com/en-us/index.html#) ([Mickel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887216/which-tools-do-you-use-to-debug-html-js-in-your-browser/1887232#1887232))
- [IETester](http://my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage) ([Mickel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887216/which-tools-do-you-use-to-debug-html-js-in-your-browser/1887232#1887232))
- [MS Expression Web SuperPreview](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=8e6ac106-525d-45d0-84db-dccff3fae677&displaylang=en) ([Rijpstra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887216/which-tools-do-you-use-to-debug-html-js-in-your-browser/3263803#3263803))

Comment: I'd be shocked if this isn't a dupe but I can't find anything offhand.

Comment: @annakata Found one I think: [Which tools do you use to debug HTML/JS in your browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887216/which-tools-do-you-use-to-debug-html-js-in-your-browser)

Comment: One question: why it's JavaScript/jQuery, and not JavaScript/ExtJS or JavaScript/MooTools, or just plain JavaScript?

Comment: 'cuz that's what I happen to use. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to question for roundup of all answers.

Answer (score 3):

`console` is your friend, available by default in newer browsers, and you can add a whole lot of debugging to IE with [FireBug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite).

For other browsers:

- [Chrome has developer tools](http://www.chromium.org/devtools/google-chrome-developer-tools-tutorial)
- [Firefox has the excellent Firebug addon](http://getfirebug.com/)

For demonstration/test cases, [jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/) is also an excellent tool.

Comment: Nick, can we make this a wiki? I can't figure out how. I want to get some responses and summarize everything in the question.

Comment: @Brad - Users can't make questions a wiki, you have to flag it for a moderator to do so :)

Answer (score 2):

If you're concerned about using console.log because not all browsers support this, it's easy to workaround with a couple lines of javascript:

```
console = console || {};
console.log = console.log || function(){}; //you can change this to do whatever you want, or leave it to just keep js errors from being thrown
```

Answer (score 1):

I love Blackbird. It's a cross-browser JS logging framework, with support for debug/info/warning/error.

You can display the console at any time with the F2 func key.

http://www.gscottolson.com/blackbirdjs/

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for an alternative for `alert(message);`, it is `console.log(message);`

The requirement is that you need any modern browser or a browser with developer tools installed.

Answer (score 1):

The Chrome Developer Tools are a direct descendant of the [Safari (WebKit) Developer Tools](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/1Introduction/Introduction.html).

Answer (score 1):

More in testing than debugging domain.

Selenium - for GUI tests

JSUnit - for unit testing