# Overlay absolute positioned, appropriately sized DIV to all blog post images?

Tags: jquery, image, dimensions

So I've got a bunch of blog posts, and each post includes an image. With jQuery, I'd like to overlay each of these images with an absolutely positioned div that conforms exactly to the size of the image it's overlaying. How can I go about this?

Every post has an image, and all images would be identical in width but would vary in height.

Here's how my post container is structured:

```
<section id="featured-posts">
  <article>
     <img src="post_image.jpg">
     <h1>Post Headline</h1>
     <div class="post-description"></div>
  </article>

  <article>
     <img src="post_image.jpg">
     <h1>Post Headline</h1>
     <div class="post-description"></div>
  </article>
</section>
```

Comment: I got a feeling this could become a Famous Question

Comment: Try here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183633/can-you-overlay-a-transparent-div-on-an-image

Comment: Updated the question to reflect that I'm looking for a jQuery solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#featured-posts article').each(function(){
    var $cont= $(this).css('position','relative'), $img= $cont.find('img');                                    
    var  pos=$img.position(), w=  $img.width(), h=$img.height();
    var $over=$('<div class="over">').css{ position: 'absolute', top: pos.top, left: pos.left, width: w, height: h, "z-index":10})
    $cont.append( $over);
})
```

You can obviously move some of the style properties to a css rule and remove the position relative if already absolue or relative

Comment: This is very close to a solution. I've added more detail to my question as well as the HTML I'm attempting to manipulate - how would I alter the code you provided to suit my specific case? Appreciate your help.

Comment: always one image per article tag, or possibly more? Or is there specific image placement within article you want to target? Still needs clarity

Comment: Yep, only 1 image per article tag. All article images would be identical in width, but will vary in height (e.g. Post #1 image is 650w x 138h, while Post #2's image is 650w x 400h).

Comment: The overlay div seems to stick to the bottom of the posts, rather than overlaying the image. Here's an example of what I'm seeing -- http://jsfiddle.net/W9dvG/1/

Comment: OK..minor tweak, when I translated from generic to real html I declared $img twice and second is invalid. http://jsfiddle.net/W9dvG/3/

Answer (score 0):

this is very much possible, and very simple indeed. you could make this a lot easier by providing any html mock up you have and by letting us know how you are going to do this. Are you loading images through ajax, php or are you going to statically place them within your html..

Either way i would suggest that you place your images within a parent div element, and add a div, as a sibling to the img.

```
<div class="contianer">
    <div class'img-wrap'>
        <img src="#" />
        <div><div>
    </div
</div>
```

you can then style those elements like so:

```
<style>
    div.img-wrap{
        width:200px;
        height: 200px;
        position:relative;
    }

    div.img-wrap img, div.img-wrap div{
        width:inherit;
        height:inherit;
    }

    div.img-wrap div{
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        left:0;
    }
</style>
```

Now the div is the same size as the image and is overlaying the image.

Hope this solved you problem, if not at least give it another shot ;)